# Ajax POST to PHP - How do I do a reply?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I have sent an email address via an ajax post from javascript to php. I have then searched the database in php to find out if this email exists in the database. How can i then send a message back to the javascript/html to say that the value was present?

This is what I used to send the request:

```
 function postEmail(){

      var checkEmail = "someone@gmail.com";

      var dataString = 'checkEmail1='+ checkEmail;

      // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "myfile.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(result){

      alert("Sent successfully");
      } 
      });
 }
```

and then in the PHP:

```
 $checkEmail2=$_POST['checkEmail1'];

 $results = mysql_query("select id from myTable where emailaddress='$checkEmail2' ");
 $row = mysql_num_rows($results);

 if ($row > 0 ) {
 echo "email already exists";
 } else {

 if ($row == 0 ) {
 echo "email doesnt exist";
 }

 }
```

Not sure if I should do a get request? Or if you return values or something. Thanks.

(p.s, Im developing a hybrid app so need to use JSON to send/retrieve from PHP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to remove second condition! output json or any other format you want. I use [json_encode for arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

try:

```
  $checkEmail2=$_POST['checkEmail1'];

  $results = mysql_query("select id from myTable where    emailaddress='$checkEmail2' ");
 $row = mysql_num_rows($results);

 if ($row > 0 ) {
     echo "email already exists";
 } else {
    echo "email doesnt exist";
  }
```

JAVASCRIPT

from your success function, print the result to the console to see the output

```
     console.log(result);
```

Comment: For some reason my email addresses are getting cut off? Do you know why that could be? If I take the @ and . out it seems to work fine? its returning it like someone@gmail.c

Comment: are you doing     echo checkEmail2 ?

Answer (score 1):

What you echo from the PHP script is sent back to the success function in the javascript, as the result parameter. So the result parameter will contain "email already exists" or "email doesnt exist"

Comment: For some reason my email addresses are getting cut off? Do you know why that could be? If I take the @ and . out it seems to work fine? its returning it like someone@gmail.c

Comment: You might need to encode the email before you make the ajax call. So you'd write: var dataString = 'checkEmail1='+encodeURIComponent(checkEmail)